# Can Tensorflow Wide and Deep model train to continuous values

Tags: tensorflow, linear-regression, lstm

I am working with the Tensorflow Wide and Deep model. It currently trains against a binary classification (>50K or not).

Can this model be coerced to train directly against numeric values to produce more precise (if less accurate) predictions?

I have seen an example of using LSTM RNNs to make such predictions using TensorFlowEstimator directly [here](http://mourafiq.com/2016/05/15/predicting-sequences-using-rnn-in-tensorflow.html), but DNNLinearCombinedClassifier will not accept n_classes=0.

I like the structure of the Wide and Deep model, especially the ability to run the linear regression and the DNN separately to determine how learnable the data is, but my application involves data that clusters, but in an overlapping, input-dependent fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DnnLinearCombinedRegressor](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn_linear_combined.py#L463) for regression problems.

Comment: There are also LinearRegressor and DNNRegressor, so the entire suite of wide and deep building blocks are available. Just what I needed!